Given three points $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ on a curved manifold, is it possible to define a triangle through the geodesics connecting them?
Let's say we have a pseudo-Riemmannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$ equipped with a metric tensor $g$. Given two sufficiently close points $x$ and $y$, the metric tensor determines a unique geodesic segment $\gamma(x,y)$ which starts at $x$ and ends at $y$.
Now, consider three points $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ on $\mathcal{M}$ and assume they are close enough that there are unique geodesics connecting them. I can construct three -a priori- different "triangular" surfaces by the following procedure: Pick a point, say, $x_1$, and create a surface by joining all geodesics emanating from $x_1$ and reaching all points on the segment $\gamma(x_2,x_3)$ connecting the remaining two points. This will create a surface $S_1$ bounded by the segments $\gamma(x_1,x_2)$, $\gamma(x_1,x_3)$ and $\gamma(x_2,x_3)$.
If I follow the same procedure, but picking a point $x_i$, I will also obtain a surface $S_i$ bounded by the segments $\gamma(x_1,x_2)$, $\gamma(x_1,x_3)$ and $\gamma(x_2,x_3)$.
My question is: Are all three surfaces $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$ the same? Is there any condition on the metric at the neighborhood of $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ that would guarantee that the three surfaces are the same? If not, is there anything useful to say about the union of all three surfaces?

Maybe it helps to consider all the surfaces obtained by using the geodesics emanating from a fixed point on any of the segments, not just the corners.
